# How to find Google Maps information like Hotels,Fuel Station, Bus Station.....?

Tags: android, maps

Hello Guys is it possible to find Hotel, Fuel Station, Bus Station location nearby using Google Maps API.

I am currently working on an app but haven't worked with Google maps before. Can any of you please provide some tutorial links for this if possible

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the following steps to find google map information
Step 1: 
   make the google map url with your latitude longitude pair to get information

Step 2: 
pass the URL to get json object

Step 3:
parse the json object to get your required data

Follow the link:

[how to get json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646346/get-json-object-without-param-name-in-android)

[json parsing tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)