# Get json object without param name in android

Tags: android, json

I have a json response like this:

```
array (
  'status' => 'OK',
  'categories' => 
  array (
    'Sepeda' => 
    array (
      83 => 'Sepeda MTB',
      'Fullbike' => 
      array (
        370 => 'MTB',
        371 => 'Roadbike',
        374 => 'Fixie',
        375 => 'Sepeda Lipat',
        378 => 'City Bike',
        380 => 'BMX',
        382 => 'Onthel',
      ),
      84 => 'Sepeda Lipat',
      'Frame' => 
      array (
        372 => 'MTB',
        373 => 'Roadbike',
        376 => 'Fixie',
        384 => 'Sepeda Lipat',
        379 => 'City Bike',
        381 => 'BMX',
        383 => 'Onthel',
      ),
```

How can I get an array from the array "Sepeda MTB" , "Sepeda Lipat" , etc

As you know , that JSON doesn't have parameter names like "value" or "name" as usual . Honestly my JSON response is not that short , but other values after that.

and when I use this code

```
JSONObject cate = json.getJSONObject("categories");
                JSONObject a = cate.getJSONObject(secid);
                Log.e("a", a.toString());
```

this logcat show this

```
> 05-20 16:38:42.840: E/a(3869): {"143":"Road Bike","144":"Kids & City
> Bike","Fullbike":{"370":"MTB","378":"City
> Bike","371":"Roadbike","382":"Onthel","375":"Sepeda
> Lipat","380":"BMX","374":"Fixie"},"96":"Helm & Body
> Protection","145":"Onthel","Wheel (Hub, Rims, dll)":{"262":"Ban
> dalam","263":"Hub & Freehub","261":"Ban
> luar","265":"Spokes","360":"Quick Release","264":"Rims","348":"Wheel
> Set"},"95":"Tas Sepeda","94":"Sepatu Sepeda","138":"Part
> Generik","93":"Part lain","Outwear":{"275":"Jersey, Glove &
> Pants","280":"Tas","276":"Helm & Topi ","277":"Sepatu","278":"Body
> Protector","279":"Goggle \/ Kacamata","359":"Bandana &
> Masker"},"91":"Jersey, Shorts & Pants","Equipment &
> Tools":{"357":"Speedometer","358":"Stickers & Decals","270":"Rack &
> Panniers","269":"Bottle & Cage","268":"Lampu \/ Senter","361":"Fender
> \/ Mudguard","272":"Carrier, Hanger, & Bike
> stand","267":"Bel","271":"Pompa","266":"Gembok","273":"Tools &
> Others"},"Fork &
> Suspension":{"353":"Fork","355":"Suspension"},"83":"Sepeda
> MTB","Frame":{"383":"Onthel","379":"City Bike","384":"Sepeda
> Lipat","381":"BMX","372":"MTB","373":"Roadbike","376":"Fixie"},"Drivetrain":{"349":"Group
> Set","136":"Part Drivetrain Lain","258":"Bottom Bracket","90":"Hub &
> Free Hub","257":"Pedal, Toeclip, & Strap","259":"Rantai","254":"Front
> Derailleur (FD)","253":"Rear Derailleur (RD)","256":"Sprocket &
> Gear","88":"Crank","255":"Crank & Chainring"},"86":"Fork &
> Shock","87":"Wheel & Tire","Control & Brake":{"250":"Seatpost &
> Clamp","251":"Saddle","252":"Headset & Spacer","369":"Cable &
> Housing","245":"Brake Set","249":"Hand grip \/ Bar tape","362":"Bar
> end \/
> Tanduk","248":"Shifter","247":"Handlebar","246":"Stem"},"142":"BMX","84":"Sepeda
> Lipat","89":"Brake & Rotor","141":"Sepeda Fixie"}
```

I've solution , this my solutin

```
JSONObject cate = json.getJSONObject("categories");
                JSONObject a = cate.getJSONObject(secid);

                //get list of keys
                Iterator<String> keys=a.keys();
                while(keys.hasNext()){
                    String key=keys.next();
                    String value=a.getString(key);
                    Log.e("key", key);
                    Log.e("value", value);
                }
```

thanks all :)

Comment: what  have you tried so far?

Comment: I've get categories using this
JSONObject cate = json.getJSONObject("categories");
JSONObject a = cate.getJSONObject(secid);

secid is String to identity "Sepeda" in first array

Comment: post the string you are getting from the server?

Comment: @blackbelt I've edit mu question, can u help me?? thanks

Comment: I can not see any json array

Comment: so can u help me , how to I get String  370 => 'MTB', and the other , to be like this , String id = 370 , and String name = MTB ?? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
//result from server
JSONObject obj=json object
//get list of keys
Iterator<String> keys=obj.keys();
while(keys.hasNext())
{
String key=keys.next();
String value=obj.getString(key);
}
```

Comment: here 'key' is ur 'id' and 'value' is ur 'name'

Comment: you're great , I use your code and it show result like this
05-20 16:52:35.455: E/key(5350): 142
05-20 16:52:35.455: E/value(5350): BMX

thanks @Akilan :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like Gson which do all the work for you, you just need to create your classes with the same name variable, and if it's an array just make List< Your object name >.

Here's the link : [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
for(int i=0;i<JsonObject.length();i++)
    {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG2,"Data Value Name "+JsonObject.names().get(i));
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();``
        }
    }
```